# Doesn't reputation counter show downvotes anymore?

Tags: support, bug

Today I've lost 15 points due to an unaccepted answer:

[image]

But if I click on the trophy of the menu bar I don't see the negative votes:

[image]

If I remember correctly, with the old menu, the negative votes were displayed.

Does my memory fail or did they change something?

Comment: The current situation is even worse: after a reduction of points (unaccepted answer, bounty ...) new reputation will not be reported until a) on clicks on the reputation icon to view the list b) the accumulated new reputation exceeds the reputation loss.

Comment: @samcarter Hence I remember well, it's a bug, I'll add the tag.